# String joining with different number of White Spaces in Java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'd like to ask if there's a way to use different delimiters or prefixes based on key value of streamed map.

Here's my code:

```
Map<String, Double> averageScoresPerTask...

String summary="\nAverage         |      "+averageScoresPerTask(Stream.of(courseResults.toArray
                    (new CourseResult[0]))).entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .map(t->String.format(Locale.US,"%.2f", t.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining(" |                "))
                    +" | "+String.format(Locale.US,"%.2f",averageTotalScore) +" |    "+mark(averageTotalScore)+" |";
```

What it prints

```
Student         | Lab 1. Figures | Lab 2. War and Peace | Lab 3. File Tree | Total | Mark |
Eco Johnny |56              |69              |90              | 71.67         |    D |
Lodbrok Umberto |70              |95              |59              | 74.67         |    D |
Paige Ragnar |51              |68              |57              | 58.67         |    F |
Average         |          59.00 |                77.33 |                68.67 | 68.33 |    D |
```

Similar problem with students but my question is regarding Average line so please ignore them.
Here's how it should look like.

```
Student         | Lab 1. Figures | Lab 2. War and Peace | Lab 3. File Tree | Total | Mark |
Eco Johnny      |             56 |                   69 |               90 | 71.67 |    D |
Lodbrok Umberto |             70 |                   95 |               59 | 74.67 |    D |
Paige Ragnar    |             51 |                   68 |               57 | 58.67 |    F |
Average         |          59.00 |                77.33 |            68.67 | 68.33 |    D |
```

So the "|" are perfectly aligned

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I use String.format in my code but didn't think of using it like that. Do you mind me asking if you know how do I combine it with ".2f" format tho? I can ofc just search on my own.

Comment: This problem, isn't related to streams (although you've implemented this task using streams), it's purely about `String` formatting.

Comment: Yes, I do apologize though I have a problem with the names still. I stream a class with Person objects that contain names. I need to format the table based on the longest name. Is this a stream problem? I wouldn't want to categorise it wrong again.

Comment: The title of the question as well as tags are meant to pinpoint the core parts of the problem. There could be lots of things used in your project, from JDK features to Frameworks, and other staff. You need to emphasize things that are most relevant to the problem. Let's say you think the problem can be resolved by dealing with Maven, then you need to reflect it in the tags/title and elaborate in the question body. And if you think that the problem can be solved by utilizing different operations in the pipeline, applying different collectors, etc. - it's a stream-related problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the length of your formatted numbers before and after the comma:

```java
String.format(Locale.US, "%14.2f", 59.3)
```

This will make your total formatted number 14 characters long, 2 of that characters will be after the comma, 1 will be the comma itself, that leaves 11 characters for the part before the comma. The number will be right aligned and padded with spaces.

Now you just have to know the length of each heading (you could store it in a list) and adjust that total length for each column. But I think that a stream is not the ideal solution here, I would prefer a loop with an index counter, this way you can access two lists by index (the list of headings or their lengths and the list of values you want to output).

Answer (score 0):

You should align also Strings not only numbers. For student the same, student name have different length.
I would extract the part that calculate averageScores as a String.

```
String averageScores = averageScoresPerTask(Stream.of(courseResults.toArray
        (new CourseResult[0]))).entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .map(t->String.format(Locale.US,"%15.2f", t.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Also don't add spaces on Collectors.joining.

And than use a single String.format like this:

```
String.format(Locale.US,"\n%20s|%s| %15.2f|%10s","Average",averageScores, averageTotalScore, mark(averageTotalScore));
```